# Using Webpack alias cause to ESLint error on import alias in WebStorm

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, webstorm, eslint

I set the alias Webpack config by the following code:

```
module: {
...
resolve: {
  alias: {
    utils: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/utils/'),
    '@SharedBlocks': path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/application/shared-blocks'),
  },
  extensions: ['.js', '.json', '.jsx', '.scss'],
},
...
```

Then I find the `ESLint` error out in WebStorm like below:

[image]

Definitely, the ESLint cannot resolve `'@SharedBlocks/explorer'` so I add an `import/resolver` to `.eslint.js` file to configure it:

```
settings: {
  "import/resolver": {
    webpack: {
      config: "webpack.template.js",
    }
  }
},
```

Now everything works well in all editors like `VSCode` and etc. **but** just in *WebStorm* I see below:

[image]

It is so weird because even running `eslint .` command doesn't return ESLint rules error but JUST in WebStorm I see red underline for `import` also works well but show red underline for `import`. It's so weird that VSCode has no any problem and works well

*How can I fix it?*

Answer (score 1):

`no-extraneous-dependencies` ESLint rule doesn't consider EsLint resolvers, see https://github.com/benmosher/eslint-plugin-import/issues/496. I'm not sure though why the error can only be seen in WebStorm. I'd suggest contacting support on this

Comment: Thanks for your answer and trying to help me. but I read this [link](https://github.com/benmosher/eslint-plugin-import/issues/496) before. it doesn't help me and your answer too. definitely the problem is for `ESlint` not for `WebStorm`, So contacting support is not a good decision. the `no-extraneous-dependencies` rule when is `off` consider `ESlint` resolver.

Comment: I doubt the `"no-extraneous-dependencies": "off"` is a true answer, but when I use it in `ESlint` rule, the red underline disappear. is it a good solution? is it a proper way?